# Kafka Rack aware setup

Tags: apache-kafka, rack

I have created a kafka cluster on AWS and made it rack aware by configuring broker.rack as AZ name in server.properties file.

1. Cluster contains 3 racks(AZ), 6 brokers
2. All brokers are in sequence i.e. 1001: AZ1, 1002: AZ2, 1003: AZ3, 1004: AZ1, 1005: AZ2, 1006: AZ3,
3. Created a topic with RF=3, partitions=18
4. Ideally, for each partition, all 3 copies(one leader and 2 replica) should be on different racks(AZ)
5. In my case, few partitions have 2(out of 3) replicas in same rack, due to which it is not rack aware setup

Is there any other config required while creating topic, or in kafka config?

Comment: Given that you created the topic after all brokers had rack awareness configured, just try to run a preferred leader election to see if that fixes your issue. I would rather rely on [cruise-control](https://github.com/linkedin/cruise-control/) for this, which is far smarter than what Kafka knows natively.